# Magento invoice vat calculation missing product vat

Tags: magento-1.9, invoice, tax, vat

I'm using magento CE 1.9.2.4, and i'm struggling with this issue:

In all of my orders invoices the vat calculation of the product is missing.

Example:
My order view which has the good calculation:
[image]

The orders invoice:

[image]

I tried to change a lot of settings, but nothing seems to work right.